# How to specify path in directory tree structure

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

From subprocess `import Popen, PIPE`

```
process = Popen(['/home/hadoop/BackupFolders/','tree','.','-d'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Hello, I am trying to run these lines of code, to show the directory tree structure like `Linux/Unix` does. I've gotten the tree structure to show but only for the current working directory.

Every time I enter the path and run,  it says `access denied`. I set the shell to true and false but it didn't work.

I want to be able to show the current working directory but also give the option to specify other paths.

Answer (score 0):

exec in unix works by passing a string of parameters such that the first parameter is the location or name of the executable and the following parameters are typically options. In the above example, your executable is 'tree', but you have `/home/hadoop/BackupFolders/` as the first element in your list, so essentially python is trying to *run* the BackupFolders directory, which is of course non sense thus an error.

Further, typically the token `.` means current working directory, so the command `tree . -d` tries to run tree on the current working directory with option -d. To change the target directory from cwd, change the . parameter. Thus `['tree','/home/hadoop/BackupFolders/','-d']` or `tree /home/hadoop/BackupFolders/ -d`.

Also a warning -- you are likely getting in over your head here. The memory on subprocesses PIPE are fixed size and POpen tends to hang when you overflow that memory size since the stdout flow never closes once it can no longer write to the pipe. tree really does not have a fix return size so there is a big risk of hanging. Replace that pipe with a temp file and read the output later. Or better thread the read from stdout and run it asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you, Sir! Your help is much appreciated, new to python.

Comment: Great answer except OP is using `.communicate` to make sure that the pipe doesn't fill. As long as output won't strain available memory, there is no need for an intermediate file.

Comment: communicate is exactly what causes the hang because it does not clear the pipe until the  running process has closed, it does not have any internal asynchronous reads.

Comment: That is not how it works. `communicate` creates threads to read stdout and stderr so that there is no blocking. That's why it exists, to safely read output and error streams without deadlocks.

Comment: Actually it will not.   From https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py `def _readerthread(self, fh, buffer):
            buffer.append(fh.read())` ... read will block until eof has been put to the stream to return, since this is the thread used to consume stdout and stderr this means it will not read until the stream is closed with eof.

Comment: I mean I get what you are saying, but there is still a risk of deadlock if the stdout is large and if the calling process blocks on a write to stdout. The calling process tries to write to stdout but is blocked since the stdout pipe is full. The communicate methods is waiting for the EOF to empty the stdout pip because of the single read in the pipe. You are in a dead lock - and can never get past the thread join in subprocess.communicate.